# Не могу разобраться в коде. Python

Tags: python, файлы, файловая-система, работа-с-текстом

Есть две функции on_create и on_modified

```
import win10toast
import time
import os
import glob
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
src="D:/temp"
toaster = win10toast.ToastNotifier()

print(len(src)+1)


def on_created(event):
   list_of_files = glob.glob(src + "/*")
   latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
   print(latest_file)

   list_of_files1=glob.glob(latest_file + "/*")
   print(list_of_files1)
   latest_file1=max(list_of_files1, key=os.path.getctime)

   list_of_files2 = glob.glob(latest_file1 + "/*")
   latest_file2 = max(list_of_files2, key=os.path.getctime)
   print(list_of_files2)
   toaster.show_toast("Объект создан", latest_file1[len(latest_file)+1:]+ " экспортировал " +"("+latest_file+") "+ latest_file2[len(latest_file1)+1:])


def on_modified(event):
   list_of_files = glob.glob(src + "/*")
   latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
   print(latest_file)

   list_of_files1=glob.glob(latest_file + "/*")
   print(list_of_files1)
   latest_file1=max(list_of_files1, key=os.path.getctime)

   list_of_files2 = glob.glob(latest_file1 + "/*")
   latest_file2 = max(list_of_files2, key=os.path.getctime)
   print(list_of_files2)
   toaster.show_toast("Объект изменен", "В папке "+src+ " был изменен объект: "+latest_file2[len(latest_file1)+1:])
```

Обе содержат одинаковый код кроме вывода уведомления. По какой-то причине в функции `on_create` список `list_of_files1` не получает значений, а в функции `on_modified` все то же самое, но там `list_of_files1` получает значения. Почему так?

Comment: а вы обе функции проверяли в одинаковой ситуации на одних и тех же данных?

Comment: вызови их в другом порядке, наверняка станет наоборот

Comment: @Zhihar Да, в одинаковой. на одних и тех же.